# Higher Resistance Measurement on Wet Tongue than Dry Tongue?

Tags: resistance, multimeter, theory, variable, resistance-measurement

I'm trying to start learning about electrical engineering as a hobby. I'm reading from a book right now, and it suggests using my multimeter to measure the resistance of my tongue while it's wet and then again after drying it thoroughly.

My wet reading is around 7M2 ohms or 7.2 Megohms, my dry reading is around 5M1 ohms or 5.1 Megohms. But the book indicates that we should be able to observe a lower resistance from a wet reading and a higher resistance from the dry reading which is the exact opposite of what I've observed here.

I've performed both measurements 3 times now, and while the values are pretty variable, the wet resistance measurement stays consistently higher than the dry resistance measurement.

I have verified the multimeter, specifically its resistance measuring functionality, is working decently by measuring the resistance of a 75K resistor.

I've been drinking water to assure my tongue is decently wet before the wet measurement. I've been thoroughly drying my tongue and the test leads before the dry measurement. I've been using a mirror to make sure I'm applying the test leads to about the same locations and distance from each other on my tongue from test A to test B.

I've also been drinking some black coffee while I work, though not between measurements, and not between swishing water around to prep for the wet test and the test itself.

What's the deal here? Am I doing something wrong? Is the book wrong? Is this just one of those weird things that's too variable to really have a decent answer?

Comment: something may be wrong with your ohmmeter or with your measurement ... my tongue measures ~40 k ohms from side to side

Comment: It's always been the case for me that a wet reading (using saliva, and never de-ionized water) was substantially lower resistance than a dry one. But the amount of surface in contact also matters a lot -- especially with the dry readings. Bottom line is that I cannot offer an explanation. Your results, as reported, are questionable.

Comment: Using water may well be the problem. Try waiting a while after eating or drinking anything so it’s mostly just saliva on your tongue.

Comment: While not helpful in any way, this link seems obligatory as it contains the "touch tongue here" directive. https://xkcd.com/730/

Comment: Try switching your multimeter to voltage - measure the voltage created by your tongue. Before doing this, check that your voltmeter has roughly 10M internal resistance. If your mouth is a voltage generator, it can influence the ohmmeter measurement. It'd be better to use an AC measurement method than an ohmmeter DC measurement.